# $E(x_i \epsilon_i) = 0$ assumption in regression, but $x_i$ non-random, so what is $E$?

Tags: regression, probability

In this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) on regression, among other places, an expectation pops up:

[image: expectation in regression]

As I understand it, the vector $\mathbf{x}$ is non-random--it is simply a vector of real numbers.  So, under what law is this expectation taken?  If it is only the law of $\epsilon$ then the result follows immediately as $\epsilon$ is assumed to have zero mean, so this equation is vacuous.  Is there a joint law implicit, or is this style of writing just non-rigorous?  If the latter, what is it trying to say?

Comment: Most treatments of regression assume $X$ is non-random, in which case that assumption is indeed unnecessary. But in case $X$ is random, that assumption is useful. By my reading of that particular paragraph, the assumption is that $X$ may or may not be random.

Comment: @JohnAustin I wouldn't say it's "most treatments", it depends heavily on the intended application. In fields where the $x_i$ are typically *chosen* as part of an experiment, then that generality may not be necessary, but in fields like econometrics where studies tend to be observational, the $x_i$ are just as random as the $y_i$, and the non-random special case is less useful.

Comment: @ChrisHaug Absolutely. I meant to say most "statistical" treatments--econometrics, machine learning, and signal processing are just a few subject areas where random design is more common.